# python tqdm and logging

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, tqdm

I'm having a python script for accessing/manipulating network devices with netmiko. To speed up the processing, I'm using now tqdm and a process pool for multiprocessing.

This is working fine except the logging stuff. The logger works fine for the main, but not for the processes created by tqdm.

The important code snippets are as follows:

```
def threaded_function(params):
    """the custom function

    :param kwargs params: device details packed as keyword arguments
    :returns: dictionary containing the results of each step
    """

    logging.debug('TEST')
    logging.info('TEST2')
    logging.error('TEST3')



def main_loop():
    logging.getLogger("netmiko").propagate = False
    logging.getLogger("netmiko").disabled = True
    logging.getLogger("paramiko").propagate = False
    logging.getLogger("paramiko").disabled = True

    log_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    LOG_FILE = os.path.basename(input_file) + '.txt'

    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    if args.log2file:
        log_format_file = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        rfh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILE, maxBytes=1048576, backupCount=10)
        rfh.setLevel(args.filelevel)
        rfh.setFormatter(log_format_file)
        logger.addHandler(rfh)

    if args.log2con:
        log_format_con = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setLevel(args.conlevel)
        ch.setFormatter(log_format_con)
        logger.addHandler(ch)

    if not args.log2file and not args.log2con:
        logger.disabled = True
        logger.propagate = False

    logging.info("JOB STARTED: " + str(log_time))


    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(max_cpu_count)
    with tqdm(total=len(input_list), ascii=True, unit="dev", desc='processing',
              disable=(False if args.log2con else True)) as t:
        for _ in pool.imap_unordered(threaded_function, input_list):
            t.update(1)
            results.append(_)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_loop()
```

Does anyone has an idea, where I'am wrong? I tried to pass a queue according the 2nd example from this doc (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) but no luck..

any help is appreciated
regs nick